# How to add portuguese-BR dictionary to xfce-dict-plugin on Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: xubuntu, plugins, xfce-panel, dictionary

I couldn't find a Portuguese-BR dict. to install on xfce-dict-plugin. I want only a Portuguese-BR dict. I already have por-eng and eng-por  installed. Appreciate some help. Thanks Vladi.

Comment: Possibly it's sufficient to install `hunspell-pt-br`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson ok, how to add to xfce4-dict-plugin ??

Comment: Don't know. In Ubuntu the `hunspell-*` dicts are available everywhere automatically. I'm not using Xfce myself.